# Finding $a+b+c$ if $a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}=25$, $\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ac}=1$, $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{25}{9}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How would you find $a+b+c$ if you know the following?
> $$\begin{align}
> a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}=25 \\[4pt]
> \frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ac}=1 \\[6pt]
> \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{25}{9}
> \end{align}$$

Can someone please provide a solution?

Comment: Here's my advice: let $k = a + b + c$. The latter two equations will tell you $ab + bc + ca$ and $abc$ as a multiple of $k$. From this, you should be able to get $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ as a function of $k$ that equals $25$, which should narrow $k$ down to a finite number of possibilities.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: I tried to make a cubic but failed, I would really like to see a solution.

Answer (score 3):

As ,  1/ab +1/bc + 1/ac =1 , therefore ,
a+b+c=abc = k(say)..(1)

Also , as 1/a + 1/b+ 1/c= 25/9,
ab+bc+ac= 25/9(abc)=25/9(k)...(2)

Now as we know ,
a³+b³+c³ -3abc=(a+b+c)(a²+b²+c²-ab-bc-ac)
OR
a³+b³+c³ -3abc=(a+b+c){(a+b+c)²-3(ab+bc+ac)}

Now putting values of (1) and (2) in this , we get

```
a³+b³+c³-3k=k(k²-3(25k/9))
```

=>25-3k=k³-25k²/3

Simplifying , we get

```
k³-25x²+9k-75=0 , which has 2 imaginary roots and one real root .
```

Real root = 25.75 (approx.)

Therefore , a+b+c=24.75(approx.)

Comment: thanks! What if it is as a common fraction